# Modify the target of a .appendChild() and it causes the program to reinitialize

Tags: javascript, function, dom, button

I am having a problem wherein I changed this line:

```
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

to this line:

```
document.getElementById("character").appendChild(node);
```

and now when I click the update button that was just working perfectly, it now reinitializes the page.  this is the function that the button calls:

```
updateList: function(){
 this.updateStats();
 this.derivedStats();
 document.getElementById("moveList").innerHTML = "";
 var strName;
 var node = document.getElementById("selectR");
 var c = node.childNodes;
 for(var i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
  for(strName in this.list) {
  if(this.list[strName].name==c[i].value) {
   //var helper = this.list[strName].display();
   //document.getElementById("moveList").appendChild(helper);
   }
  }
 }
},
```

Comment: Reinitialises the page? What does that mean?

Comment: that section of the program is rather large, but I have an onload="" on my body tag that runs a function to create the page, which is where the lines I changed are.  Before I made that change, it was working perfectly, now it is causing the onload function to be run over again.

Comment: I'm afraid the information you shared is not enough to see what's going wrong. You say you change a line but don't show the context of that line change. The function you claim is called when it happens is calling other functions that probably others again, etc.

Comment: the context is 92 line long function that consists of a bunch of elements and textnodes being created and assembled, this line is the last line in the sequence that adds the whole kit to the HTML page.  the button in question is defined in the function and has its on click behavior defined as well.

Comment: the only realistic way for me to share all of this program for you to look at it is to upload it to my website... give me a couple minutes to do that

Comment: http://www.adamferestad.com/dnd/testStuff.html

ok, here is a link to the page.  This is everything that I have done so far. the update button is the one in question, but both buttons are redoing the page.  I have an alert as the first line of the onload function to show the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No magic here, input of type "button" causes form submission, page reloads.

Comment: thank you so much... I moved the form for the combo boxes into the table cell rather than wrapping the table and it works perfectly now.  Thank you so much.